# Insert a new row (with Date-time index) at the end of each group in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to Python and now I have a table look like this:

```
**YearMonth**    language     Rate

2018-01            en         0.093 
2018-02            en         0.084 
2018-03            en         0.088

...

2018-12            en         0.079 
2019-01            en         0.088 
2018-01            fr         0.094 
2018-02            fr         0.078 
2018-03            fr         0.087

... 
2018-12            fr         0.084 
2019-01            fr         0.079
```

Now, I want to insert some rows to the end of each language based on conditions: 
e.g.

**2019-02** ,  **en** ,  **some value** (*if 2018-02 > 0.9 then avg(the value of the previous 3 month/3) else avg(the value of the previous 3 month/4)*)

**2019-02** ,  **fr**  ,  **some value** (*if 2018-02 > 0.9 then avg(the value of the previous 3 month/4) else avg(the value of the previous 3 month/5)*)

How can I approach this question? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use if need last 3 rows of groups for averages:

```
#values for division by language
dTrue = {'en':3, 'fr':4}
dFalse = {'en':4, 'fr':5}

#get mean of 3 last value of group
s = df.groupby('language')['Rate'].apply(lambda x: x[-3:].mean())
print (s)
language
en    0.085000
fr    0.083333
Name: Rate, dtype: float64

#filter rows by YearMonth and set new YearMonth
df1 = df[df['YearMonth'] == '2018-02'].assign(YearMonth='2019-02')
print (df1)
  YearMonth language   Rate
1   2019-02       en  0.084
6   2019-02       fr  0.078

#compare Rate and set division number by map of dictionaries
div = np.where(df1['Rate'] > 0.9, df1['language'].map(dTrue), df1['language'].map(dFalse))
print (div)
[4 5]

#division with mapped by Series s
df1['Rate'] = df1['language'].map(s) / div
print (df1)
  YearMonth language      Rate
1   2019-02       en  0.021250
6   2019-02       fr  0.016667
```

---

```
#add to original and sorting 
df = df.append(df1).sort_values(['language', 'YearMonth']).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   YearMonth language      Rate
0    2018-01       en  0.093000
1    2018-02       en  0.084000
2    2018-03       en  0.088000
3    2018-12       en  0.079000
4    2019-01       en  0.088000
5    2019-02       en  0.021250
6    2018-01       fr  0.094000
7    2018-02       fr  0.078000
8    2018-03       fr  0.087000
9    2018-12       fr  0.084000
10   2019-01       fr  0.079000
11   2019-02       fr  0.016667
```